# insert and update if a record exists else not , race condition

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-express, exists, race-condition

```
if exists (select itemcode from item where itemcode=1120)
update item 
set itemname = 'laptop'
where itemcode = 1120

else 
insert into item (itemcode,itemname)
values (1120,'laptop')
```

it will be used by multiple users. will this query give a race condition.
if yes, then how?what shall i use in place of this query?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Only inserting a row if it's not already there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407857/only-inserting-a-row-if-its-not-already-there)

Comment: also read http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522522.aspx

Comment: Actually the duplicate I linked to isn't a true duplicate. I see you are doing an `upsert`. Yes there will be a race condition. In SQL Server 2008 you would use `Merge`. For 2005 see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2522379/atomic-upsert-in-sql-server-2005

Comment: @AndersUP - Yes I discovered that since too and link to that article in [the possible dupe](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3408211/73226)

Answer (score 1):

You may use `transaction` for this. Make sure to lock all your required tables in single transaction then release them.

```
begin transaction

begin try

    if exists (select itemcode from item where itemcode=1120)
    BEGIN
    update item 
    set itemname = 'laptop'
    where itemcode = 1120
    END

    else 
    BEGIN
    insert into item (itemcode,itemname)
    values (1120,'laptop')
    END

    commit transaction

end try

begin catch
  raiserror('Message here', 16, 1)
  rollback transaction
end catch
```

You can also give name to your transaction if you have multiple.