# Why is the target table of a MERGE statement not allowed to have enabled rules?

Tags: sql-server-2008, merge

We have a process updating the database which uses the following SQL

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Target_Table WHERE Target_Table_ID = ...)
BEGIN
    INSERT ...
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    UPDATE ...
END
```

I wanted to change this to use a `MERGE` statement in order to avoid a possible race condition where the `IF` and then `INSERT` or `UPDATE` statements are evaluated separately.

However, as soon as I executed the query I got the error:

> The target table 'Target_Table' of the MERGE statement cannot have any enabled rules.  Found rule 'TargetTable_RULE'

I understand the documentation states that the table cannot have rules enabled, although I missed it when first reading it, and apart from disabling the rule before performing the `MERGE` (which I don't see as a workable solution) it seems I'm stuck with the `IF NOT EXISTS` solution.

What the document does not explain is *why* the target table is not allowed to have rules. In my case the rule is a simple `> 0` check on a value.

Does anyone know why rules are not allowed in this situation and if there is another way to perform the upsert in an atomic way?

**EDIT:** As Andriy M commented the question [Atomic UPSERT in SQL Server 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2522379/atomic-upsert-in-sql-server-2005) already has a wealth of information on atomic upserts so I'll not duplicate the discussion here. Instead I'd like just to know why the `MERGE` statement cannot execute on tables with rules defined and is there a work-around?

Comment: For more information, you might start with [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2522379/atomic-upsert-in-sql-server-2005), then follow its *Linked* section as well as some the linked questions' *Linked* sections.

Comment: @Andriy M - Thanks for the link, I had a search around but didn't find that question as it's not concerned with using `MERGE` but it's very helpful. I'm tempted to close my own question but I'd still like to know why I cannot perform a `MERGE` on a table with rules.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Rules are old feature of SQL Server.
- [This feature will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188064.aspx). I think, this is the reason why `MERGE` statement does not supports tables with rules.
- You can replace *rules* with *check constraints*.

MERGE example (with rules & with `CHECK` constraints):

```
CREATE RULE MyRule
AS 
@Status IN ('Y', 'N');
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.SalesOrder
(
    SalesOrderID INT PRIMARY KEY
    ,OrderDate DATETIME NOT NULL
    ,IsDeleted CHAR(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N'
);
GO

EXEC sp_bindrule @rulename='MyRule', @objname='dbo.SalesOrder.IsDeleted';
GO

INSERT  dbo.SalesOrder (SalesOrderID, OrderDate)
SELECT  1, '20110101'
UNION ALL
SELECT  2, '20110202'
UNION ALL
SELECT  3, '20110303';
GO

SELECT  *
FROM    dbo.SalesOrder;

PRINT '*****First test*****';
GO

MERGE   dbo.SalesOrder Dst
USING   (VALUES (1,'Y'), (4,'Y')) AS Src(SalesOrderID, IsDeleted) 
ON      Dst.SalesOrderID = Src.SalesOrderID
WHEN    MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET IsDeleted = Src.IsDeleted
WHEN    NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN INSERT (SalesOrderID, OrderDate, IsDeleted) VALUES (Src.SalesOrderID, GETDATE(), Src.IsDeleted);
GO

EXEC sp_unbindrule 'dbo.SalesOrder.IsDeleted'; --Disabling `MyRule` for IsDeleted column
ALTER TABLE dbo.SalesOrder --We "replace" the old rule with a new `CHECK` constraint
ADD CONSTRAINT CK_SalesOrder_IsDeleted CHECK( IsDeleted IN ('Y', 'N') );
GO

PRINT '*****Second test*****';
MERGE   dbo.SalesOrder Dst
USING   (VALUES (1,'Y'), (4,'Y')) AS Src(SalesOrderID, IsDeleted) 
ON      Dst.SalesOrderID = Src.SalesOrderID
WHEN    MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET IsDeleted = Src.IsDeleted
WHEN    NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN INSERT (SalesOrderID, OrderDate, IsDeleted) VALUES (Src.SalesOrderID, GETDATE(), Src.IsDeleted);
GO

SELECT  *
FROM    dbo.SalesOrder;

DROP TABLE dbo.SalesOrder;
DROP RULE MyRule;
```

Results:

```
Rule bound to table column.

(3 row(s) affected)
SalesOrderID OrderDate               IsDeleted
------------ ----------------------- ---------
1            2011-01-01 00:00:00.000 N
2            2011-02-02 00:00:00.000 N
3            2011-03-03 00:00:00.000 N

(3 row(s) affected)

*****First test*****
Msg 358, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
The target table 'Dst' of the MERGE statement cannot have any enabled rules.  Found rule 'MyRule'.
Rule unbound from table column.
*****Second test*****

(2 row(s) affected)
SalesOrderID OrderDate               IsDeleted
------------ ----------------------- ---------
1            2011-01-01 00:00:00.000 Y
2            2011-02-02 00:00:00.000 N
3            2011-03-03 00:00:00.000 N
4            2011-09-20 16:03:56.030 Y

(4 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: Thanks for your analysis and explanation. I was using a DB design tool which created the constraints as rules so I'll look in to changing that.