# T-SQL Update else Insert best approach

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Atomic UPSERT in SQL Server 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2522379/atomic-upsert-in-sql-server-2005)

I am using the following construct to insert a new record if it does not exists. If it exists then it will update that record. I am wondering that if it is thread safe. I mean two threads try to insert record which will create duplicate entries. What is the best approach to handle such type of queries? Do I need to put these statements in a transaction block?

```
UPDATE Table1 SET (...) WHERE Column1='SomeValue'

IF @@ROWCOUNT=0
    INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES (...)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a more detailed explanation of Andomar's post. I am giving the credit to Andomar, just illustrating how it could be more detailed and corrected a small bug.

```
DECLARE @s VARCHAR(100)
SET @s = 'somevalue' 

DECLARE @t TABLE (column1 VARCHAR(100), column2 VARCHAR(18))

INSERT @t 
SELECT @s, 'First example'
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM @t WHERE Column1 = @s) 
IF @@rowcount = 0 UPDATE @t SET column2 = 'Second example' WHERE Column1 = @s

-- at first the value does not exists and is inserted
SELECT * FROM @t

-- same script again, notice how the second example is chosen because it already exists
INSERT @t 
SELECT @s, 'First example'
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM @t WHERE Column1 = @s) 
IF @@rowcount = 0 UPDATE @t SET column2 = 'Second example' WHERE Column1 = @s

-- new the line exists and column 2 is updated
SELECT * FROM @t

column1     column2
----------- -------------
somevalue   First example

column1     column2
----------- --------------
somevalue   Second example
```

Answer (score 4):

It's a bit safer if you do the insert first:

```
insert Table1 (...columns...) select ..values... where not exists (
    select * from table1 where Column1 = 'SomeValue')

if @@rowcount = 0 update Table1 set (...) where Column1 = 'SomeValue'
```

That way, the check for existance and insert are part of the same statement.  So there is no room between the `update` and the `insert` where another connection could insert the row.

Comment: Incorrect syntax of Insert statment. SQL Server does not like it. I think I can use serializable lock.

Comment: @Andomar: `WHERE` is not essentially part of `INSERT`, therefore it cannot be used with `INSERT...VALUES`. But it *can* be part of `SELECT`, which means you can use `WHERE` with `INSERT...SELECT`.

Comment: @kumar, Andriy M: You're right, edited in answer