# How do I write a simple insert or update in T-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000, upsert

I have a process that I do not want to track if something is a create or an update.  Tracking would be complex.  I would like to perform a create OR update. The schema is like...

```
col1 varchar() (PK)
col2 varchar() (PK)
col3 varchar() (PK)
col4 varchar()
```

I am thinking about doing

```
TRY
{
    INSERT ...
}
CATCH(DuplicateKeyException)
{
    UPDATE ...
}
```

What do you suggest?

---

I want to ensure that I understand the other top voted answer. Given my schema, the UPDATE always occurs (even with an INSERT), but the insert only occurs where it does not exist?

```
 //UPSERT
INSERT INTO [table]
SELECT [col1] = @col1, [col2] = @col2, [col3] = @col3, [col4] = @col4
FROM [table]
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    -- race condition risk here?
    SELECT  1 
    FROM [table] 
    WHERE [col1] = @col1 
        AND [col2] = @col2
        AND [col3] = @col3
)

UPDATE [table]
SET [col4] = @col4
WHERE [col1] = @col1 
    AND [col2] = @col2
    AND [col3] = @col3
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using (including version)?

Comment: AKA [upsert](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upsert).

Comment: Sorry guys, SQL 2000.  Updated post.

Comment: `Merge` not available then. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2522379/atomic-upsert-in-sql-server-2005/2525343#2525343

Comment: @Martin - I think this qualifies as a dupe then

Comment: @JNK - Maybe.  That question specifically addresses SQL 2005 though.

Comment: @P.Brian - look at it and see if it takes care of your issue :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
update table1 set col1=1,col2=2,col3=3 where a=1
if @@ROWCOUNT=0
   insert into table1 (col1,col2,col3) values (1,2,3)
```

I think its quicker than checking existance first.

Comment: +1 - Dont use the link from @Martin saying this is a DUP.  The UPSERT code there causes intermittent errors that are very hard to pinpoint.  If you want to use that method, then see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263445/sql-c-primary-key-error-on-upsert

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey I get the distinct impression you didn't read that answer properly but just blindly copied the code. The text explains why it doesn't work and gives an alternative.

Comment: @Martin - I'm no SQL expert, but I don't agree with his logic.   I don't see why it's necessary to go through a page worth of "atomic operation" detail when all you need to do is take off the FROM.  To me, that answer is the definition of over-engineering.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [MERGE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) statement (if you're using T-SQL) or build a query that does an INSERT or UPDATE based upon the existence of your key.

**Edit**: OP has edited his question.  Yes, you'll technically be running the UPDATE and INSERT every time this query is executed, but you'll only touch the table with one of those statements depending on which criteria is met.